# Should I resolve factor collinearity before hedging?

Tags: equities, hedging, factor-models, factor-loading, market-neutral

Goal: I want to run a portfolio, daily or weekly rebalanced, with a target idio vol %. Thus I will be market neutral, sector neutral and maintain some style exposure at 70-80% idio overall.

Okay, this is easy with my stock universe, expected returns for each stock, and covariance of each stock's returns to the market, sector and style factors. Toss it into an optimization routine with a risk budget constraint.

Here's the problem though: the sector and style factors have collinearity with 1) each other and 2) the market.

So my questions are twofold:

1. Is the collinearity a problem? Can I simply estimate factor loadings for each stock the standard way, by doing a multivariate weighted regression of its returns on the returns of each factor? Then the betas are estimated simultaneously, but I doubt it will be robust, and I expect the hedging accuracy and risk attribution to suffer.
2. If the collinearity is an issue, how shall I solve it? I was thinking I could regress each sector and each style against the market, and then proceed as described above. But then the betas are not as actionable and I'd have to back out the originals. Or is there another preferable way?

I have not seen a question that addresses this specific issue, and would be interested in any other answers that tackle this end to end.

Comment: My 0.02 USD. Generally OLS regression can deal with some multicollinearity (only extreme colinearity causes the procedure to break down completely) and the resulting slope estimates are valid. The precision of the affected estimates deteriorates (by the so-called Variance Inflation Factor), but I do not think the t-stats are particularly important in a hedging situation. I would use the OLS hedge, it should be a valid hedge.

Comment: nbbo2's advice sounds fine. Alternatively, you could try ridge regression instead of OLS. Ridge regression is more robust to multicollinearity.